# Bug in border: solid 2px #ddd (chrome)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm having trouble with chrome edge, I need it to be 2px. She gets with aspect of 3px when I click on a button to expand the table row and show another  hidden by clicking the button again to close the  that was hidden, and then appears with 3px !! The funny thing is that when I click anywhere on the screen, the 3px aspect   automatically returns to 2px

[image]

```
$( ".ver-mais" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

$(document).on('click', 'a.ver-mais',function() {

var el2 = $(this).attr('data-detail-detail');
        if ($('#'+el2).css('display') === 'none' )
        {
            $(this).text('See less');
      $('#'+el2).attr('style','display:table-row;');
     }
     else{
            $(this).text('See more');
            $('#'+el2).attr('style','display:none;');
        }

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/427/

some solution? thanks!! ps. In IE11 it's works 100%

Comment: We'll need some code buddy.

Comment: @Achshar https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/427/

Comment: @FábioZangirolami you need to add your code to your post.

Comment: Ah jeez, I can see it but when I open dev tools it doesn't happen anymore. Woha. What sorcery is this. PS that code is a mess.

Comment: I suggest keep reducing the code. Keep deleting stuff until it doesn't happen anymore. Then you'll know.

Comment: @Achshar I've done everything and cannot find the problem! =/

Comment: Find the bare minimum code that still has the problem. That usually helps. For example you currently have a ton of extra html, remove all the unnecessary bits.

Comment: impossible!!! this is a bug of chrome!!!!!

Comment: @Achshar solution alternative --> `tbody:before {

  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;

}` takes only First <td > What I want to catch The first <td> and the second <td> **full line

Comment: @Achshar fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/458/

Comment: @Achshar I'm happy!! I got the expected result! https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/461/ niceeeeeeeee! ;) tks for help...